# How to read the txt file of the link taken in axios?

Tags: javascript, file, vue.js, axios

i want to read , text of file in rest API

[image]

i am using **marked** for convert txt to markdown and show to vue.js

But I do not know how to read the contents of the file

I also saw **raw-loader** in my search, but I do not know how to give contents of the file text in axios

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to read the file from the server at runtime or include it in your app at design time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a syntax like below to read the text file:

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/markdownFile/test.txt').then(function(response){
    this.markDownData = response.data
});
```

Then you can set the `markDownData` variable to your view

Comment: this answer is true . but we must add this code :

    let self = this ;
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/markdownFile/test.txt').then(function(response){
    self.mark= response.data;